# JAVAC is not in the jdk path but java -version says JDK is installed

Tags: java, jdk

When I type javac in the terminal, this is what I get:

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * gcj-4.5-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I want to try the suggestions from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864640

But I can't find the reference to the javac. I expected to find javac inside /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin but it's not there.

What should I do to get javac working since it's not where it is supposed to be?

This is what I get for **java -version**:

> java version "1.7.0_25"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

so I guess JDK is properly installed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something like `locate -br ^javac$` ?

Comment: yes Samues, but no results are displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems  you have  installed JRE (Java Runtime Environment) only. `javac` comes under `JDK` (Java Development Kit) package.
To install `JDK`, open terminal and type following command:

> `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you ten times. Why on earth openjdk installs the JRE and the JDK in the same directory?